# convert value of type 'Result?' to type 'String'

Tags: arrays, swift, casting

I have problems to cast my array of type 'result' to an array of string. This is what I already tried:

EDIT:
I need the information as String type since I want to use the URL as image source.

**swift4**

```
let message = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Welcome.self, from: data)
let imageURLs = message?.children.attachment.results.filter({ $0.metadata.mediaType == "image/png" })
let latestImageURls = imageURLs?.prefix(2)
let latestImageURlsArray = Array(latestImageURls ?? [])

let image1 = self.view.viewWithTag(63) as! UIImageView
let image2 = self.view.viewWithTag(64) as! UIImageView
let image3 = self.view.viewWithTag(65) as! UIImageView

let url1 = URL(string: latestImageURlsArray[0]) // error:Cannot convert value of type 'Result' to expected argument type 'String
let url2 = URL(string: latestImageURlsArray[1]) // error:Cannot convert value of type 'Result' to expected argument type 'String
let url3 = URL(string: latestImageURlsArray[2]) // error:Cannot convert value of type 'Result' to expected argument type 'String

image1.kf.setImage(with: url1)
image2.kf.setImage(with: url2)
image3.kf.setImage(with: url3)
```

Comment: What do you need an `Array` for? What is the `ArraySlice` insufficient for?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no such thing as `[Array]`, I guess you're talking about `Array<Result>`. An array of `Result` object. What is the same as `[Result]`.

If for some reason you want to create a new `Array` object from you `ArraySlice`, just call an initializer.

```
let resultsArray = Array(latestImageURls ?? [])
```

**UPDATE**

You're saying that you also need to convert your `Result` objects into `String`, but you disn't explain what is the `Result` object and how does it how is it related to the `String`. Does it **contain** it or it **is** a String? So I'll try to assume.

If you want to `cast` you objects into `String`, you can do it like that

```
let latestImageURlsArray = resultsArray.compactMap { $0 as? String }
```

If you want to `extract` your strings from results if they have it, (let's say that it's stored at `imageURL` parameter) you can do it like that

```
let latestImageURlsArray = resultsArray.compactMap { $0.imageURL }
```

After that, `latestImageURlsArray` will be an `[String]`.

If the relation is completely different and more complicated, please add more details about the `Result` class, so I could make my answer more specific.

Comment: `ArraySlice` is optional

Comment: @Carpsen90 Sure, you're right. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @YuryImashev: Yes, good answer but still I am having trouble to convert the types. Now I have the problem to convert from "result" to "string". I need the string as source for pictures I want to display. -> I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

1. You're not doing any "casting", you're just saying "I expected a `[Array]`". You're not doing anything to make that be the case. In any case, that's not even valid, because `Array` isn't a valid type.
2. As you see, `prefix` returns an `ArraySlice<T>`, which provides a lightweight view into the memory of `Array<T>`, without copying any elements.

Comment: "because Array isn't a valid type". Note that `Array` might be a valid type when used as a return type in an Array instance property or method extension and it is equivalent to `[Element]` type inference

Comment: @LeoDabus Yeah I know, but by the balance of probabilities, it probably isn't in such a context.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the way you convert an `ArraySlice` of a given type to an `Array` of that type is to use the Array initializer:

```
struct Thing {
}

let things = [Thing]()
let sliceOfArrayOfThings = things.prefix(2)
let arrayOfThings = Array(sliceOfArrayOfThings)
```

In your case your Array is actually an Optional array, so you have to take some extra steps to deal with the optionality, as described by Yury in his answer:

```
let things: [Thing]? = []
let sliceOfArrayOfThings = things?.prefix(2)
let arrayOfThings = Array(sliceOfArrayOfThings ?? [])
```